# How are variables made available to expression evaluator scope? how to add my own?

Tags: java, jsp, el

I am trying learn more about JSP expression evaluations. How and which variables are determined to be in scope for access by expressions?

I have a simple JSP (ELEvaluator is a convenience wrapper)

```
<% String foo = "bar"; %>
<%= ELEvaluator.evaluate("${foo}", request, pageContext) %> //-> blank
<%= ELEvaluator.evaluate("${1 + 1}", request, pageContext %> // -> 2
```

Do these vars/objs have to exist on the request obj? or be registered with the pageContext/Evaluator?

Thanks

Comment: Put your mouse above the `[el]` tag which you placed below the question until an info box pops up and then click therein the *info* link.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`${foo}` means

- find a page-scope attribute named "foo" and, if not found
- find a request-scope attribute named "foo" and, if not found
- find a session-scope attribute named "foo" and, if not found
- find an application-scope attribute named "foo"

So, if you want some object to be available to the EL, store it in the appropriate scope:

```
pageContext.setAttribute("foo", theObject);
// or
request.setAttribute("foo", theObject);
// or
session.setAttribute("foo", theObject);
// or
servletContext.setAttribute("foo", theObject);
```

Comment: Thanks - this is great info. How would I call theObject.test("cat") in the EL?

Comment: You would use `${foo.test('cat')}`, but only if you're using the latest unified EL. Previous versions are limited to properties access. Follow the advice of BalusC in his comment to your question.